# Apache Camel + IBM MQ + Spring Boot + SSL

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, apache-camel, ibm-mq

I want to use Apache Camel to get a message on IBM MQ in a spring boot project. I am currently setting up the JMS component, but I can't find any docs on how to to this with SSL.

This is what I have so far..:

```
@Bean
    public MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory() {
        MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setHostName(host);
        try {
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setChannel(channel);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setPort(port);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setQueueManager(queueManager);
            // Some kind of SSL authentication should be here
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return mqQueueConnectionFactory;
    }
```

Is there anyone to help me? Any link, documentation, ...?

Thanks a lot in advance

Could not find a lot of clear or recent examples

Comment: Try `mqQueueConnectionFactory.setSSLCipherSuite("VALID_CIPHER_SUITE")`.  This should match the SVRCONN channel.

Comment: Only that? So no configuration or anything similar?

Comment: You need at least a trust store, java comes with a default cacerts.   You didn't provide any requirements other than "how to to this with SSL".  What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: I have to setup a camel rest api which sends messages to a JMS endpoint using IBM MQ. But the IBM MQ does not use username and password what you see in most example, but it's with a SSL certificate.

Comment: Do you have a cert to use?

Comment: Yes it is stored in Openshift. So I have to create a configmap and deployment.yml to parse it as a variable in my code I think

Comment: If would need to be in JKS or PKCS12 and you would reference it via the key store and trust store java system properties.